# How to create, update, and delete calendar events with on @click methods using Fullcalendar, Laravel, and Vue3

Tags: javascript, laravel, fullcalendar, vuejs3, fullcalendar-5

I have created a working install from the https://fullcaledar.io for Vue3 and TypeScript that functions just like the demo here:
https://fullcalendar.io/demos

Further, I've connected the Vue calendar component to my CRUD for creating events and have those events showing up on the Fullcalendar view.

I'm having difficulty formulating the code based on the handleDateSelect and handleEventClick methods that will create or modify the calendar events I created through CRUD in the database.

Straight from the demo at https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar-example-projects/blob/master/vue/src/DemoApp.vue

```
        /* you can update a remote database when these fire:
        eventAdd:
        eventChange:
        eventRemove:
        */
```

How do I get the handleDateSelect and handleEventClick methods to trigger these eventsAdd, eventChange, eventRemove events and contribute data to the database?

here's my resources/js/calendar/Index.vue:

```html
<template>
    <head title="Dashboard" />
    <BreezeAuthenticatedLayout>
        <template #header>
            <h2 class="font-semibold text-xl text-gray-800 leading-tight">
                Resource Calendar Timeline
            </h2>
        </template>
        <div class="py-12">
            <div class="max-w-10xl mx-auto sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
                <div class="bg-white overflow-hidden shadow-sm sm:rounded-lg">
                    <div class="p-12 bg-white border-b border-gray-200">
                    <!--start calendar-->
                      <div class='demo-app'>
                        <div class='demo-app-sidebar'>
                          <div class='demo-app-sidebar-section'>
                            <h2>Instructions</h2>
                            <ul>
                              <li>Select dates and you will be prompted to create a new event</li>
                              <li>Drag, drop, and resize events</li>
                              <li>Click an event to delete it</li>
                            </ul>
                          </div>
                          <div class='demo-app-sidebar-section'>
                            <label>
                              <input
                                type='checkbox'
                                :checked='calendarOptions.weekends'
                                @change='handleWeekendsToggle'
                              />
                              toggle weekends
                            </label>
                          </div>
                          <div class='demo-app-sidebar-section'>
                            <h2>All Events ({{ currentEvents.length }})</h2>
                            <ul>
                              <li v-for='event in currentEvents' :key='event.id'>
                                <b>{{ event.startStr }}</b>
                                <i>{{ event.title }}</i>
                              </li>
                            </ul>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class='demo-app-main'>
                          <FullCalendar
                            class='demo-app-calendar'
                            :options='calendarOptions'>
                                <template v-slot:eventContent='arg'>
                                    <b>{{ arg.timeText }}</b>
                                    <i>{{ arg.event.title }}</i>
                                </template>
                          </FullCalendar>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </BreezeAuthenticatedLayout>
</template>
<script setup lang='ts'>
import BreezeAuthenticatedLayout from '@/Layouts/AuthenticatedLayout.vue';
import { head, Link } from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue3';
import '@fullcalendar/core/vdom'; // solves problem with Vite
import FullCalendar from '@fullcalendar/vue3';
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid';
import timeGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/timegrid';
import listPlugin from '@fullcalendar/list';
import resourceTimelinePlugin from '@fullcalendar/resource-timeline';
import interactionPlugin from '@fullcalendar/interaction';
import axios from 'axios';
// import { INITIAL_EVENTS, createEventId } from '@/components/event-utils.ts';
// import { INITIAL_RESOURCES, createResourceId } from '@/components/resource-utils.ts';
</script>
<script lang='ts'>
export default {
  components: {FullCalendar},
  data() {
    return {
      calendarOptions: {
        plugins: [
          dayGridPlugin,
          timeGridPlugin,
          resourceTimelinePlugin,
          listPlugin,
          interactionPlugin // needed for dateClick
        ],
        events: [],
        headerToolbar: {
          left: 'promptResource prev,next today',
          center: 'title',
          right: 'resourceMonth,dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listMonth'
        },
        views: {
          resourceMonth: {
          type: 'resourceTimelineMonth',
          buttonText: 'personnel'
          }
        },
        customButtons: {
          promptResource: {
            text: "+ personnel",
        click: function() {
          var title = prompt("Name");
          if (title) {
            calendar.addResource({
              title: title
            });
            fetch("add_resources.php", {
              method: "POST",
              headers: {
                Accept: "application/json"
              },
              body: encodeFormData({ title: title })
            })
              .then(response => console.log(response))
              .catch(error => console.log(error));
          }
        }
      }
    },
      initialView: 'resourceTimelineMonth',
      editable: true,
        selectable: true,
        selectMirror: true,
        dayMaxEvents: true,
        weekends: true,
        select: this.handleDateSelect,
        eventClick: this.handleEventClick,
        eventsSet: this.handleEvents,
        /* you can update a remote database when these fire:
        eventAdd:
        eventChange:
        eventRemove:
        */
        resourceAreaHeaderContent: 'Personnel',
        filterResourcesWithEvents: false,
        resourceGroupField: 'building',
        resources: [],
      // initialEvents: INITIAL_EVENTS,
      } as CalendarOptions,
      currentEvents: [] as EventApi[],
    }
  },
  created() {
            this.getEvents();
            this.getResources();
        },
  methods: {
    getEvents() {
      axios.get('show-events')
        .then(response => {
            this.calendarOptions.events = response.data.events;
            });
        },
      getResources() {
          axios.get('show-resources')
            .then(response => {
                this.calendarOptions.resources = response.data.resources;
                });
          },
      handleWeekendsToggle() {
          this.calendarOptions.weekends = !this.calendarOptions.weekends // update a property
        },
      handleDateSelect(selectInfo: DateSelectArg) {
        let title = prompt('Please enter a new title for your event')
        let calendarApi = selectInfo.view.calendar
          calendarApi.unselect() // clear date selection
            if (title) {
          calendarApi.addEvent({
            id: createEventId(),
            title,
            start: selectInfo.startStr,
            end: selectInfo.endStr,
            allDay: selectInfo.allDay
            })
        }
    },
    handleEventClick(clickInfo: EventClickArg) {
      if (confirm(`Are you sure you want to delete the event '${clickInfo.event.title}'`)) {
        clickInfo.event.remove()
      }
    },
    handleEvents(events: EventApi[]) {
      this.currentEvents = events
    },
  }
}
</script>
<style lang='css'>
h2 {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
}
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 0 1.5em;
}
li {
  margin: 1.5em 0;
  padding: 0;
}
b { /* used for event dates/times */
  margin-right: 3px;
}
.demo-app {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100%;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.demo-app-sidebar {
  width: 300px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  background: #eaf9ff;
  border-right: 1px solid #d3e2e8;
}
.demo-app-sidebar-section {
  padding: 2em;
}
.demo-app-main {
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 3em;
}
.fc { /* the calendar root */
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.fc-day-today
{
background-color: var(--fc-today-bg-color, rgba(255, 220, 40, 0.15));
}
.fc-day-sat, .fc-day-sun
{
background-color: var(--fc-today-bg-color, rgba(255, 100, 40, 0.15));
}
</style>
```

Comment: Your post is a reasonable question, but could use some clarification. What do you mean by 'have a working solution?' Do the handleDateSelect and handleEventClick events fire?

Comment: I've updated my question per your suggestions. Yes, the handleDateSelect and handleEventClick events DO fire. They create events rendered on the calendar, but they do not create events in the database.

Comment: it's still not clear from your post where the connection to the database happens. It looks like perhaps handleDateSelect and handleEventClick methods are javascript events and you want some kind of AJAX to trigger server-side events named eventsAdd, eventChange, eventRemove.

Comment: `they do not create events in the database`...ok, and which bit of your code do you think is responsible for doing that part? As far as I can see, you haven't written anything which would try to achieve that.

Comment: @ADyson the code provided in the example suggests that when the eventAdd, eventChange, and eventRemove events are fired, they can contribute information to the database...I'm just asking for an example on how to fire them? I assume they could be connected to the eventClick handlers...I just don't know how?

Comment: Well for example: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventAdd - eventAdd is an option you can set in fullCalendar, and you can give it a callback function which runs when an event is added to fullCalendar (which could be done e.g. via the `calendarApi.addEvent()` method). It's nothing to do with clicking on an event, but you would handle it in just the same way as you handle eventClick, by assigning to a function to be run when it occurs - e.g. `eventAdd: this.handleEventAdd.` and then `methods: .... handleEventAdd() { ... }` further down.

Comment: It's just a hook so that _you_ can write code to do something when that adding has happened. What code you write depends on how you want to interact with your remote server. Javascript running in a browser cannot update a database directly...you'd need to (for example) send an AJAX request to a server-side script which could then do the database update. You've tagged this post with Laravel, so if you have a laravel backend, you can send a request to that.

Comment: @ADyson in another question here, I managed to retrieve events from a JSON feed via axios with this in my component method
`getEvents() {
      axios.get('show-events')
        .then(response => {
            this.calendarOptions.events = response.data.events;
            });`
Can I not construct a similar axios.post method for pushing of event data to the database? 
`handleEventAdd(){
      axios.post('show-events')
        .then(response => {
            this.calendarOptions.events = response.data.events;
            });
    },`

Comment: `Can I not construct a similar axios.post method `...yes you can. What makes you think you can't? Have you tried?

Comment: Yes, I have tried...I'm just not certain of the syntax...I've found some good examples without using Vue and some with Vue 2...but there have been a lot of changes in Laravel and Vue since they were published...I get a "method not allowed" error when trying to post to that same JSON endpoint I've successfully retrieved the event data from

Comment: In laravel you'd just need a standard action method which accepts a post request, reads the data submitted to it, and updates the database. Nothing special about that. And axios has its own documentation and is independent of Vue, you can just use it to construct a normal post request and include the event data in the payload. Where exactly did you get stuck in your attempts?

Comment: `when trying to post to that same JSON endpoint `...why would you post to the same endpoint?? You need a different function for updating than for just fetching existing data.

Comment: @ADyson I'm still struggling with this. I've found a way around using Livewire, but I've added in additional fields for the events. Could you please provide an example or hint at how I should structure the JSON endpoint to post data to as well as the Axios/and or Fullcalendar options for such a post action?

Comment: It would help if you could update the question with what you've achieved so far, then we can focus on the precise bit you're stuck on. Bear in mind I'm not a Laravel expert by a long way.

Comment: @ADyson, I'm trying hard not to be obtuse here...What I've managed to got working is with a completely different set of dependencies for laravel. I think I'd be better off starting a new question for where I'm stuck. In brief, this version of my code has a backend CRUD interface that creates events, but all the FullCalendar drag and drop, addEvent and remove event actions don't work. The Jestream/Livewire version I've built has all the working FullCalendar actions fully functional, but the backend CRUD doesn't work...I'll hack at it some more